# Corrupted piping InputStream to OutputStream of Process (ProcessBuilder)

Tags: java

I want to do something like this in Java:

`cat 2.webp | exiftool -`

`cat 3.webm | ffmpeg -hide_banner -i -`

Here is a code I have written – check `getInputStreamFromCommand` method:

```java
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        InputStream input1 = getInputStreamFromCommand("exiftool -", fromResource("1.png"));
        printStream(input1);
        InputStream input2 = getInputStreamFromCommand("exiftool -", fromResource("2.webp"));
        printStream(input2);
        InputStream input3 = getInputStreamFromCommand("ffmpeg -hide_banner -i -", fromResource("3.webm"));
        printStream(input3);
    }

    // Check this out
    public static InputStream getInputStreamFromCommand(String command, InputStream pipedInputStream) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

        processBuilder.command("cmd", "/c", command);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        pipedInputStream.transferTo(process.getOutputStream()); // transferTo is Java 9 API

        return process.getInputStream();
    }


    public static InputStream fromResource(String filename) {
        return Main.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
    }

    public static void printStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

But this works partially incorrect: exiftool shows a part of an expected result and a warning what the image is corrupted:

`Warning: Corrupted PNG image`

`Warning: Error reading RIFF file (corrupted?)`

ffmpeg does not work at all.

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Just $0.02 here .. there's a good amount of code there.  To help figure out exactly where the issue starts, I would suggest to 1) distill your code here up until the point where it runs without error - meaning empty each method that returns type `void`, 2) start adding back in your code one line at a time (running the build each iteration) until it breaks/fails .  Once you reach that point, you can see the delta between the working code and what is causing it to break. That will give you a reference for point for which part is already valid, and what remains to resolve

Comment: If you use Java 9+, consider using [`ProcessBuilder.startPipeline()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#startPipeline(java.util.List))

Comment: Welp, it's a synchronisation problem as a result – losing a part of data. I use `processBuilder.start()` and only after that pipe i-stream to o-stream. But there is no way to do it before `start()`. Other approach to do it is to use `processBuilder.redirectInput(file)`, but it requires to create a temp file from i-stream first, that I don't want to do. Imho, they should enhance API, `redirectInput` should be able also to receive `InputStream` as argument. Currently you can pipe `InputStream` after `start()`, I need way to do it before.